# jquery copy text from one input to another while typing

Tags: jquery

I have text editor quilljs

I would like to copy it's content to INPUT field **while** user typing the content.

From "editor-container" to "testMsg"

HTML

```
  <div id="editor-container"></div>
   <input type="text" name="testMsg" id="testMsg">
```

JS

```
$('#replyBox').submit(function() {
    var value = $('#editor-container');
    var input = $('#testMsg');
    // value.val() // get the value first
    input.val(value.val());     
});
```

Comment: What have u tried so far in jquery?

Comment: what kind of text editor do you have? I can't type on #editor-container if is a div.

Comment: Provide more details like which text editor are you using? What you have done so far?

Comment: @Roy - i edited my post

Comment: @Anuresh - i edited my post

Comment: `.on('keyup')` might be a good research point

Comment: you need an event on #editor-container => keypress, keyup instead $('#replyBox').submit(function() {

Answer (score 3):

Normally if you want to have a mirrored typing effect you'd register the `input` event on the [form control](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xforms-20020118/slice8.html) (ex. `<input>` or `<textarea>`) that's typed in then assign its value to the value of the "ghost" form control.

The quills plugin doesn't use a form control it generates `div.ql-editor` with the [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) attribute.

1. `div`s don't have a `value` so you'll have to target its content as text or HTML.
2. `input` event is for form controls that accept text so a `keyboard` event needs to be used instead.

BTW `submit` event is when form data is sent to a server. When dealing with form controls, events like `input` and `change` are more suitable when you are not sending to a server. Refer to **[this section](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/)** for more on form events with jQuery.

### Demo

```css
#text {
  font: inherit;
  display: block;
  width: 99%;
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>


  <fieldset>
    <div id='editor'></div>
    <input id='text'>
  </fieldset>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
  <script>
    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
      theme: 'snow'
    });
    $('.ql-editor').on('keyup', function() {
      $('#text').val($(this).text());
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```